# giving char value as array index gives wrong output

Tags: c++

I gave a char c, value (c='1') as array index to print
and it gave me a wrong output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    cin>>a[1]; //5
    char c ='1';
    cout<<c<<" "<<a[c];

}
```

I expect the output of 5, but the actual output is some random number

Comment: `'1'` is not equal to `1`.

Comment: `cout << int(1) << ' ' << int('1');` might prove illuminating.

Comment: See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). The character `'1'` has the ASCII value of `49` (decimal) or `0x31` (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output code is equivalent to:

```
cout << c << " " << a[int(c)];
```

In other words:

```
cout << '1' << " " << a[49];
```

That is just an undefined behavior. Enjoy the nasal demons.